# ¿Cómo guardo un array de inputs de un form en una tabla de MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, formularios

Tengo la siguiente página llamada *notas.php*:

[image: Pagina]

Y este es el código que tengo, lo que hace es seleccionar los alumnos e imprimir sus notas.

```
Seleccione notas a agregar:
<select id="combito">
  <option>Notas</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>

Seleccione la materia:
<select id="combito">
  <option>Materia</option>
  <option value="lenguaje">Lenguaje</option>
  <option value="matematicas">Matematica</option>
</select>

<div id="div_1" class="contenido">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>RUT</td>
        <td>Nombre</td>
        <td>Apellido</td>
        <td>Notas</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root", "","liceo");

    if (!$connect) {
      die(mysqli_error());
    }

    $results = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT rut, nombre, apellido FROM alumnos");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($results)) {
      $rut = $row->rut;
      $boo = 0; /* Iniciamos la Variable Auxiliar
      que indicará cuantas notas se imprimió  por cada Alumno  */
      $results2 = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT nota FROM notas WHERE rut_alumno = '$rut' AND id_materia=1 LIMIT 1");
    ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?=$row->rut?></td>
        <td><?=$row->nombre?></td>
        <td><?=$row->apellido?></td>
        <td>
          <?php
            while($nota = mysqli_fetch_object($results2)):
          ?>
            <input type="text" name="pin" maxlength="2" size="2" value="<?=$nota->nota?>">
            <?php
              $boo +=1;/* Incrementamos después de Imprimir la nota del Alumno*/
            endwhile;

            /* Si la variable es menor a 2 , es decir no se imprimieron las 2 notas respectivas*/
            if($boo<1){ 
              /* 
              Imprimimos  inputs de value 0 hasta que sea < 2 , dado que si el
              el valor de $boo es 1 o 0 , primero se realizará el echo y luego el incremento
              Sí $boo es 0 -> Iteración 0 - Imprime el input - Incrementa $boo -> $boo = 1
                Iteración 1 - Imprime el input - Incrementa $boo -> $boo = 2
                Termina el for dado que 2 no es menor que 2
              Sí $boo es 1 -> Iteración 0 - Imprime el input - Incrementa $boo -> $boo = 2
                Termina el For dado que 2 no es menor que 2
              */
              for (; $boo < 1; $boo++) { 
                echo '<input type="text" name="pin" maxlength="2" size="2" value="10">';
              }
            }
          ?>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

El problema es que no sé cómo guardar todos los "inputs" que se generan. Por ejemplo si tengo 11 nombres habrán 11 inputs generados, y si hay 12 alumnos habrán 12 inputs que se generarán también. Entonces, me gustaría saber cómo guardar el valor de esas notas, en mi tabla.

Esta es mi tabla *notas*

[image: tabla]

Comment: Lo necesitas en PHP y HTML o podemos incluir con front-end framework como Jquery?

Comment: @AlbertoSiurob también podría ser, sería ideal si me guiaras

Comment: Pregunto... si se genera un `input` por cada nombre, y lo estás generando con `php`, ¿por que no asignar un `name="id_alumno"` para reconocer que `input` pertenece a que nombre cuando recibas el `POST`? Teniendo esta asociación, independientemente del número de nombres que tengas, podrás decidir, que hacer con cada `input`, crear o actualizar, y a quién le asignas esa operación. Se puede hacer perfectamente sin necesidad de usar `javascript`.

Comment: Hola @OscarR, intenté recibir los valores con un foreach pero sólo recibo 2 valores; el primer input y el último input. Se supone que si hay 12 debería recibir los 12, y en eso estoy

Comment: @GeorgeHermsilla he añadido una respuesta con los detalles de la sugerencia del comentario anterior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me imagino que usas un formulario para enviar los datos de los distintos `input`.

El problema que estás teniendo, es que los `input` al enviarlos (vuelvo a suponer) por `POST`, los recibes en el servidor con las mismas `key's` que `name's` tienen los `input`.

Ejemplo:

```
<input type="text" name="pin" maxlength="2" size="2" value="10">
<input type="text" name="pin" maxlength="2" size="2" value="11">
<input type="text" name="pin" maxlength="2" size="2" value="12">
                         ^^^ Este name
```

En el servidor, la variable `$_POST` si la pasas por `var_dump()`, a pesar de que hay 3 `input's` teóricos que recibir, te retornará algo así:

```
array (size=1)
  'pin' => string '12' (length=2)
```

> Un `array` en el mismo nivel no puede tener dos `key's` iguales.
>   [Manual php](http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.array.php): Si varios elementos en la declaración del array usan la misma clave, sólo se utilizará la última, siendo los demás son sobrescritos.

Entonces, citando el comentario de la pregunta:

> ¿por que no asignar un `name="id_alumno"` para reconocer que input pertenece a que nombre cuando recibas el `POST`?

Siempre que no se impriman nombres repetidos y un solo `input` por cada nombre en cada ciclo del bucle solo debes asignar `$row->rut` a cada `name`.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($results)) {
      echo '<input type="text" name="' . $row->rut . '" maxlength="2" size="2" value="' . $nota->nota . '">';
      // o
      // printf('<input type="text" name="%s" maxlength="2" size="2" value="%s">', $row->rut, $nota->nota);
}
```

Igual para el segundo `input`.

El `POST` recibido ahora tendría una estructura así:

```
array (size=7)
  '18.357.849-9' => string '55' (length=2)
  '18.588.511-9' => string '10' (length=2)
  '18.408.578-k' => string '10' (length=2)
  //...
```

Con la asociación de cada `input` a cada alumno, solucionamos el problema de los `input's` que no recibimos.

**Para guardar los datos**

Habría que hacer un par de cambios en los select y la forma de gestionarlos. Lo planteo y decides si hacerlo o no.

Al igual que tienes el `select` *Notas* con las `id` númericas como valores. Sería interesante hacerlo también en Materia además de añadirles su correspondiente `name`.

```
<select name="nota" id="nota">
    <option value="">Notas</option> 
    //...
</select>

<select name="materia" id="materia">
    <option value="">Materia</option>
    <option value="1">Lenguaje</option>
    <option value="2">Matematica</option>
</select>
```

Solo quedaría decidir donde procesamos el formulario enviado. En la misma ruta u otra distinta.

*Solo añado el `script` básico para guardar los datos para que lo adaptes según las necesidades*.

```
// comprobar si POST está definido y si se han asignado los select nota y materia
if( isset( $_POST ) && ( !empty( $_POST['nota'] ) && !empty( $_POST['materia'] ) ) ) {
    // asignar las variables "estatícas" en el bucle
    $idNota  = (int)$_POST['nota'];
    $materia = (int)$_POST['materia'];
    // eliminarlas de POST para que no se procesen en el bucle
    unset( $_POST['nota'] );
    unset( $_POST['materia'] );
    foreach( $_POST as $alumno => $nota ) {
        $sql  = "INSERT INTO notas (id_nota, rut_alumno, id_materia, nota) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
        // preparar la sentencia
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare( $connect, $sql );
        // asignar variables
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'isii', $idNota, $alumno, $materia, $nota);
        // ejecutar la sentencia
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    }
}
```

*Si hay errores comenten y edito*

---

#### Edición 1

Para pasar menos parámetros a la consulta solo tienes que restarlos.

Cada signo de interrogación `(?,?,?)` de la consulta es sustituido por una variable, en el mismo orden que aparecen `$alumno, $materia, $nota`.

Las letras (`sii`) usadas en `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` [indican con la inicial](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#refsect1-mysqli-stmt.bind-param-parameters), igual, en el mismo orden, el tipo de valor que contiene, respectivamente son `string`, `integer`, `integer`.

```
//...
$sql  = "INSERT INTO notas (rut_alumno, id_materia, nota) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
//...
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sii', $alumno, $materia, $nota);
```

Comment: Te agradezco por guiarme, implementé el código pero aún así no se me están agregando. Le asigné los mismos nombres que me indicas, hasta agregué los combos que me diste y sin modificar el script para recibir y guardar pero tampoco me toma los valores ingresados

Comment: @GeorgeHermsilla Debe haber algo que no conecta correctamente. He probado tu código con las ediciones sugeridas y funciona perfectamente. Utiliza var_dump($_POST)para comprobar que los datos que recibes por POST son los esperados. Incluye debajo de la pregunta principal, los cambios que has realizado. Incluido la parte correspondiente al formulario.

Comment: El array se generó correctamente, tenías razón. Te vuelvo a agradecer por guiarme. Pero sólo se insertó una fila en la tabla de la db, es decir el primer dato del array y no todos los del array. Debe ser porque en la sentencia INSERT INTO notas (id_nota, rut_alumno, id_materia, nota) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?), la columna id_nota es única. Intenté dejar el id_nota como autoincrementable y quitarla del insert, pero me pide si o sí ese parámetro. Sabes cómo podría insertar sólo (rut_alumno, id_materia, nota) y no (id_nota, rut_alumno, id_materia, nota) ?

Comment: @GeorgeHermsilla he modificado la respuesta con la edición que comentas y una breve explicación sobre la estructura de la consulta preparada.

Comment: Funciona a la perfección, te agradezco tu guía. Marcaré la respuesta y la modificación a la pregunta. Como consulta adicional, el array me cambia 18.807.597-5 por 18_807_597-5. Hay manera de cambiar los guiones bajos por puntos?

Comment: @GeorgeHermsilla Es otra de las sugerencias, la `key` de un array no puede contener puntos, entonces hay dos opciones, una los sustituyes antes de guardar con `str_replace('_', '.', $alumno)` (por ejemplo), y la otra alternativa, que no se exactamente como tienes estructurada las tablas, sería usar el `id` clásico auto-incremental, que es clave única, y `rut` lo tienes definido como una columna más de información. [Aquí puedes ver el manual](http://php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php) de la función que comento.

Answer (score 1):

Este debería ser el PHP así lo construí. El output será nuestra variable en la que iremos concatenando nuestro HTML.

```
<?php 
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root", "","liceo");//CONEXION
if (!$connect) {
die(mysqli_error());
$output = "";
$sql = "SELECT n.nota,a.rut, a.nombre, a.apellido FROM alumnos a inner join notas n on a.rut = n.rut_alumno";//CONSULTA

$result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);//ALMACENAMIENTO DE RESULTADO
if (!mysqli_num_rows($result))//SI LA CONSULTA ESTA MAL HECHA
  echo 'Ocurrió un error en la consulta';
else 
{
  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) <= 0)//SI LA CONSULTA NO TRAJO NADA
  echo 'La consulta no regresó información';
  else 
  {
    //ARMAMOS EL HTML
      $output.='
      Seleccione notas a agregar:
        <select id="combito">
            <option>Notas</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
        </select>
        Seleccione la materia:
        <select id="combito_materia">
            <option>Materia</option>
            <option value="lenguaje">Lenguaje</option>
            <option value="matematicas">Matematica</option>
        </select>
        <table border="1">
          <thead>
          <tr>
          <td>RUT</td>
          <td>Nombre</td>
          <td>Notas</td>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>';
          while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) //RECORREMOS EL RESULTADO
          {
            $output.='
            <tr>
              <td>'.$row["rut"].'</td><!--PONEMOS EL IDENTIFICADOR DEL ALUMNO-->
              <td>'.$row["nombre"].' '.$row["apellido"].'</td><!--CONCATENAMOS EL NOMBRE Y APELLIDO-->
              <td><input type="text" id="'.$row["rut"].'" value="'.$row["nota"].'"></td><!--PONEMOS UN INPUT PERO QUE TENGA EL ID DEL ALUMNO PARA DIFERENCIARLOS -->
            </tr>';
          }
          mysqli_free_result($result);//LIBERAMOS EL RESULTADO
          $output.='
          </tbody>
          </table>
          <input type="button" id="envia_notas" value="Guardar notas">';//CREAMOS EL BOTON
  }
}

echo $output;
 ?>
```

Este código lo escribí el Jquery, así que tendrás que bajarte la librería de

> https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){//PREPARAMOS LAS FUNCIONES CUANDO LA PAGINA ESTE LISTA
  $(document).on('click','#envia_notas',function(){ //DETECTAMOS EL CLICK DEL BOTON
    var materia = $('#combito_materia').val();
    var arr = []; //CREAMOS UN ARREGLO VACIO
    $('input').each(function(){ //RECORREMOS TODOS LOS INPUTS
      if ($.isNumeric($(this).val())) //VALIDAMOS QUE LO QUE SE ESCRIBIO SEA UN NUMERO
      {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');//SACAMOS EL ID QUE LE PUSIMOS A LOS INPUTS EN EL PHP
        var calif = $(this).val();//SACAMOS LA CALIFICACION;
        var cadena = id+' '+calif;//CONCATENAMOS EL ID Y LA CALIFICACION
        arr.push(cadena);//METEMOS LA CADENA EL EL ARREGLO
      }
    });

    $.ajax({//ABRIMOS UNA CONEXIÓN CON AJAX
      url:'envia_notas.php',//TENEMOS QUE TENER PREPARADO UN CODIGO EN PHP Y DARLE LA RUTA DONDE IRA A DEPOSITAR LOS datos
      method:'POST',//LE DECIMOS A AJAX COMO TIENE QUE VIAJAR
      data:{arr:arr,materia:materia},//MANDAMOS EL ARREGLO CON TODOS LOS ALUMNOS Y CALIFICACIONES, Y LA MATERIA LO QUE NECESITES
      success:function(response)//PREPARAMOS UNA respuesta
      {
        alert(response);//MOSTRAMOS LA RESPUESTA
      }
    })
  });
});
```

Por último este es tu backend

```
<?php 
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root", "","liceo");//CONEXION
if (!$connect) {
die(mysqli_error());

if(isset($_REQUEST["cadena"])){$cadena = $_REQUEST["cadena"];}else{$cadena = "";}//RECUPERAMOS LAS VARIABLES ENVIADAS POR AJAX Y VERIFICAMOS QUE TENGAN INFORMACION
if(isset($_REQUEST["materia"])){$materia = $_REQUEST["materia"];}else{$materia = "";}//RECUPERAMOS LAS VARIABLES ENVIADAS POR AJAX Y VERIFICAMOS QUE TENGAN INFORMACION

$res = 0;
$arr = explode(','$cadena);//PARTIMOS LA CADENA PARA SACAR A CADA ALUMNO Y SU CALIFICACION
for ($i=0; $i <count($arr) ; $i++) //RECORREMOS EL ARREGLO QUE ACABAMOS DE ARMAR E INSERTAMOS UN REGISTRO POR CADA VUELTA DEL FOR
{ 
  $inside_arr = explode(' ',$arr[$i]);//PARTIMOS LA CADENA DONDE VAMOS, SI RECUERDAS LE PUSIMOS UN ESPACIO ENTRE EL ID DEL ALUMNO Y LA CALIFICACION ASI QUE NOS PARTIRÁ EN 2 elementos
  //EL PRIMERO TIENE EL ID DEL ALUMNO Y EL SEGUNDO LA CALIFICACION
  $sql = "INSERT INTO NOTAS (RUT_ALUMNO,ID_MATERIA,NOTA) VALUES('".$inside_arr[0]."',".$materia.",".$inside_arr[1].")";//PREPARAMOS LA CONSULTA
  mysqli_query($connect,$sql);//ENVIAMOS LA CONSULTA
  if (mysqli_affected_rows($connect)>0) //PREGUNTAMOS SI SE INSERTO CORRECTAMENTE
  {
    $res = $res++;
  }
}

if ($res == count($arr)) //VALIDAMOS QUE SE HAYAN INSERTADO EL MISMO NUMERO DE ALUMNOS QUE LOS QUE LLEGAMOS POR AJAX
{
  echo 'Se insertaron correctamente los datos';
}

else 
{
    echo 'Una o más consultas fallaron';
}


 ?>
```

Espero que te sirva, lo hice con expertise, quizá salga un error pero será fácil depurarlo. No tengo una máquina de pruebas disponible pero ya sabes por donde va la onda.

De esta forma, insertarás el mismo número de calificaciones que alumnos que estas trayendo de la base de datos por que lo armamos dinámico.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Mira la solucion que te propongo es que utilices el un INSERT INTO con sus respectivas variables y despues utilices la sentencia SELECT

Saludos es espero que te sirva

Comment: Hola, precisamente eso es lo que no sé cómo pasarle los datos al insert. Porque si hay una cantidad fija de estudiantes (10) sería fácil. Pero si hay 10, y luego añado uno habrán 11, entonces no podría pasarle ese nuevo estudiante si defino una cantidad fija.

Comment: Hola @Francisco. ¿Podrías incluir el código de cómo lo que estás comentando resolvería el problema?

Comment: en ese caso te propongo que utilices una sentencia if en el contador

Answer (score 0):

Soy relativamente nuevo en programar HTML, Mysql Y PHP, pero tengo que hacer una lectura  de una tabla en HTML que se crea después de leer una tabla de usuario de Mysql, el contexto es simple ya que es pasar la lista de asistencia de un curso. La tabla consta de 4 columnas , donde esta la lista de los alumno, nombre,  DNI , la fecha del día y por ultimo un  con "Presente" "Ausente" y  "Justificado".

Lo que necesito es recorrer la lista entera y grabarla en MYSQL con PHP y obtener desde la lista el campo seleccionado por el profesor, que puede ser cualquiera de los 3 campos anteriores mencionados.

He leído muchos post de esto , pero ninguno me ha funcionado y otros que realmente no los entiendo.

Espero me puedan dar una mano con esto ya que necesito cerrar la lectura de la lista del curso y grabarlo en mysql.

Saludos desde Stgo, de Chile en Cuarentena.

Les Saluda atte.

Rodrigo JR.